# Air-core transformer measurement using LCR meter

Tags: lcr, inductance-measurement

Is it possible to measure the magnetizing and leakage inductances of an air-core transformer (coupled coils with no ferrite core) normally using LCR meter? I want to get the values of magnetizing inductance and leakage inductances of the air-core coupled coil that I would be making for different values of coil distance. So basically, I want to plot magnetizing inductance vs coil distance and leakage inductance vs coil distance.

I have measured inductances way back then but the coil (transformer) I measured back then has a ferrite core. I shorted the secondary and connected the LCR probe to primary to measure the Lleakage while I left the secondary open to measure Lmagnetizing. Will this work too on an coupled coil with air core?

I am expecting an increasing leakage inductance as coil distance increases, while magnetizing inductance decreases with coil distance increase.

Comment: Yes, you can measure a transformer that way. Take care that any adjacent pieces of metal are in the same configuration for measurement and use, as they may affect the inductance parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, take notice to Neil_UK advice. But the problem is that the inductance will be very small because the is no magnetic core. You can measure the magnetizing inductance if your LCR meter can hanlde the nH range but I don't know if you can measure leakage inductance because it is much smaller than magnetizing inductance, unless your coil has thousand of turns.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to measure the magnetizing and leakage inductances of
>   an air-core transformer (coupled coils with no ferrite core) normally
>   using LCR meter?

1 turn of about 300 mm diameter wire produces about [1 uH](https://www.eeweb.com/tools/loop-inductance). If your transformer has more than 1 turn then the magnetization inductance should be a lot higher because inductance is proportional to turns squared. However, with an air core not all the flux from one coil couples to another so it's somewhere in the realm of 50% to 90% of the turns squared.

This will give you an idea about the magnetization inductance and this is only applicable to the driven winding so no need to worry about it changing with distance. However, you may still want to measure the perceived primary inductance when the secondary is at distance x and is shorted because from those numbers you can start to work out leakage inductances.

If both send and receive coils are identical then you have fewer measurements to make. Be aware of eddy current induction effects into local metals altering perceived inductance values.

Comment: Wait.. From your 3rd paragraph: "This will give you an idea about the magnetization inductance and this is only applicable to the driven winding so no need to worry about it changing with distance. "
Do you mean that the magnetizing inductance shouldn't vary with distance? (Say gap is 1mm compared to like 50mm)

Comment: Magnetization inductance is constant however, coupling inductance is not and this is not the same as mag inductance. Are you mistaking the two terms?

Comment: Sorry, I am still reading about magnetics stuff honestly. I do know coupling factor (k) which ranges from 0 to 1 (with 1 being perfectly coupled)... Is the coupling inductance you're saying also the mutual inductance? I am more familiar with mutual inductance (and I know mutual inductance changes based on distance in an air-core transformer)

Comment: Yes, the mutual inductance is the couped inductance but it isn't the magnetization inductance unless the coils are 100% coupled and unloaded on the secondary. I know it's confusing so keep plugging away.